# Visual Studio MSWord Addin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word

i am creating a plug-in for MS Word to monitor copy/paste event. As we have Wordsavehandler to monitor save events ,i am not finding any eventhandler to monitor copy/paste or cut/paste.can anyone suggest eventhandlers to use? Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) I think that XMLAfterInsert and XMLBeforeDelete events are what you're looking for.